# Can't share pictures using Facebook API

Tags: facebook, api, permissions

I'm quite new to the Facebook API, and at the moment I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK. So, I was interested on sharing a certain picture automatically from facebook (like http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10150286544861729&set=a.10150286544851729.375565.20531316728&type=1) on my wall (/me/links/).
So, at the POST request, I send the parameters "source" and "link", referring both to the same URL (the image URL). But I get the OAuthException "(#1500) The url you supplied is invalid".

I've permitted both "publish_stream" and "share_item" permissions, but the most awkward thing is that it seems there isn't any problem with my code, but with the app settings somehow, since I get the same error if I use the Graph API Explorer, generating an access token with the same permissions.

What am I missing here?

Nevermind, now the graph API explorer is working fine, I just generated another token and it worked fine. So, the problem may be with the code, so here it goes:

```
    $share = $facebook->api('/me/links', 'POST', array(
                            'source' => urlencode($temp_test),
                            'link' => urlencode($temp_test),
                            ));
```

Is there anything wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can not share image which are hosted on facebook. What you can do it copy that image first on your server using PHP [copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function and pass then pass the URL of image from your server.

```
i.e copy("http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10150286544861729&set=a.10150286544851729.375565.20531316728&type=1", "/folder location on your server/image.jpg");

$share = $facebook->api('/me/links', 'POST', array(
                            'source' => "http://yourserver.com".$folder_path.$image,
                            'link' => urlencode($temp_test),
                            ));
```

Comment: What about if I delete "source" and just use "link"? Would I still need to copy the image to my server?

Comment: And I know it's getting a bit persistent, but why can I share an image (passing the paramater "link" to a facebook picture) on Graph API Explorer but I can't do it in my app?

Comment: Don't have a very good idea about this but think if you have a link for an image but user set some privacy on that image how can fb allow to post that image by your app?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have an image in your album on Facebook and want to share the image on your timeline or a friend's, then you can use the object_attachment tag.  This is how you do it in Obj-C:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   //                                 @"http://www.bitsonthego.com", @"link",
                                   {image id of your image goes here}, @"object_attachment",
                                   @"my profile", @"name",
                                   @"description", @"description",
                                   @"name of the post", @"name",
                                   @"caption of my post", @"caption",
                                   @"a message", @"message",
                                   nil];

    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

No need to make another copy of your image or host it locally.